# How to create fixed navbar flex

Tags: html, css, angularjs, flexbox, angular-material

I want to design a layout for my web application with angular material design with their layout that build on flexbox.

On codepen, I try to create the layout that I want but it does appear like I wish.

```
   <html lang="en" ng-app="StarterApp">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/0.8.2/angular-material.min.css">
  </head>
  <body layout="column" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
    <div flex layout="row" layout-align="center center" style="border: 1px solid #FF00FF; height: 30px; position: fixed;">
      <h1>Please make me fixed</h1>
    </div>
    <div flex layout="row" layout-align="center center" style="border: 1px solid #FF00FF; height:30px; position: fixed;">
       <h1>Please make me fixed</h1>
    </div>
    <div layout="row" flex>

    </div>
    <!-- Angular Material Dependencies -->
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.6/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.6/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.5/angular-aria.min.js"></script>

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/0.8.2/angular-material.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

1. Create a fixed navbar, that consist of two bulks with different colors.
2. A div flexbox with flex value 30.

Comment: How do you want to position your navbars?
On the top and at the bottom of your page?

Comment: Not sure if i understand you correct. Please have a look - is this what you wanted? http://codepen.io/zhorzh/pen/qEJdEj